# Java Integer Pyramid

Tags: java, formatting

I'm working on an assignment that asks a user to input an integer between 1-15 and then displays an integer pyramid for the number of rows they selected.

I have everything working, but if the number enters an integer greater than 10, I'm getting tripped up by the extra space needed for a double digit number. I've attached my code below. If anyone could provide a little help it would be greatly appreciated.

```
int lines = input.nextInt();
for (int row = 1; row <= lines; row++)
{
    for (int column = 1; column <= lines - row; column++) 
    {
        System.out.print("  ");
    }
    for (int num = row; num >= 1; num--)
    {
        System.out.print((num>=10)?+num:" "+num);
    }
    for (int num = 2; num <= row; num++)
    {
        System.out.print((num>=10)?+num:" "+num);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

With my current code, if the user entered 13, it would produce the following output:

```
                         1
                       2 1 2
                     3 2 1 2 3
                   4 3 2 1 2 3 4
                 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5
               6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6
             7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
           8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
         9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
       10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 910
     11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
   12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
```

I just need to figure out how to get the extra space for the double digit integers. The desired output would be:

```
                         1
                       2 1 2
                     3 2 1 2 3
                   4 3 2 1 2 3 4
                 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5
               6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6
             7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
           8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
         9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
      10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
   11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

Comment: What would you like the output to look like? There's probably more than one way to prevent the numbers from running together, and you'll have to choose what you want before you can implement it.

Comment: I'd just like to get a space between the double digit integers. The numbers greater than 9 need a space in between them, like the rest of the digits 1-9 currently have.

Comment: Actually *showing* what you want, rather than just describing it, will go a long way here.

Comment: @Chalmers Hi, I have added a solution that gets you your desired output, and it should be able to handle any input value.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have chosen to do this the (slightly) harder way.

The easy way would be to reserve three spaces for each number (so that single digit numbers would have two spaces between them).

What you have chosen to do is variable spacing depending on the actual length of the numbers in each column. The first step is to change your output statements to the following:

```
    System.out.print(" "+num);
```

So you will always print one space between numbers on each row. If you run that, you'll notice that it almost works except the top part of the triangle is misaligned. To fix that, you'll have to adjust your

```
    System.out.print("  ");
```

statement so that the number of spaces it prints in each column depends on the value of the number that will appear in each column later on. To do this, you'll have to work out some arithmetic involving `column` and `lines`, to choose between `"  "` (two spaces) and `"   "` (three spaces). It's straightforward but I'll let you work out the details.

It is possible to further extend this idea to support 100 lines or more, but it's not clear that you need that capability.

Comment: I was about to say that this could use a code example, but remembering that this was an assignment I approve of you not including one

Comment: Thank you, Greg! I'll do some work with your suggestion and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Well the spacing is now fixed, but the extra space is pushing each line >9 forward one additional space. I honestly have no idea how to essentially backspace in Java code. I've included the new output at the bottom of my original comment, as the spacing isn't working here.

Comment: Yes, okay, so you've got to the point where I said "you'll notice that it almost works...". Keep going, you'll have to adjust a bit more code.

Comment: It appears that once I reach the 10th line, I need to move the columns one space to the left to account for the extra spacing for the double digit number. And for the 11th line would need to move 2 spaces to the left, and so on. How I accomplish that, I don't know. And the more things I try the further I'm getting away from the desired goal.

Comment: @Chalmers You're thinking about moving some lines to the left. The problem is, there isn't any more room to the left. You'll have to think about moving other lines to the *right* instead.

Comment: Ahah! So the middle of lines 1-9 needs to line up to the 1 in line 15. Then I need to push lines 11-14 over accordingly. Lines 1-9 would move 6 spaces to the right, line 10 would move 5 spaces, line 11 would move 4 spaces, and so on.

Comment: Greg - I've been working on this a few hours a day for the past couple days, and I have yet to get it them to line up. Would you mind throwing me a bone? I'm driving myself crazy. Thank you.

Comment: @Chalmers: In your `for` loop that prints only spaces, you will need to determine how many spaces you need to print based on the width of the number that will (eventually) appear in that column. The number that will appear in a given column is `lines-(column-1)`. So check if that is `>= 10` or not on each loop iteration, to determine whether to print three spaces or two.

Answer (score 0):

I was interested in solving this, so wrote a simple solution for your task. Seems to work for any `lines` value.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int lines = 100;
    for (int row = 1; row <= lines; row++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < calculateOffset(row, lines); i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print(row);
        for (int num = row-1; num >= 1; num--) {
            System.out.print(" " + num);
        }
        for (int num = 2; num <= row; num++) {
            System.out.print(" " + num);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

private static int calculateOffset(int row, int totalRows) {
    return calculateSpace(totalRows) - calculateSpace(row);
}

private static int calculateSpace(int columnsCount) {
    int categoryLowest = 1;
    int categoryHighest = 9;

    int categoryDigits = 1;

    int charactersUsed = 0;

    while (categoryLowest <= columnsCount) {
        int categoryItems = Math.min(categoryHighest, columnsCount) - categoryLowest + 1;

        int numbersCharacters = categoryDigits * categoryItems;
        int spacesCharacters = (categoryItems - 1);
        boolean previousCategoryIncluded = categoryLowest > 1;
        int spaceBetweenCategoriesPresent = previousCategoryIncluded ? 1 : 0;

        charactersUsed += numbersCharacters + spacesCharacters + spaceBetweenCategoriesPresent;

        categoryHighest = categoryHighest * 10 + 9;
        categoryLowest *= 10;
        categoryDigits++;
    }
    return charactersUsed;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but your solution is quite a bit beyond what we've currently learned, and it would be quite obvious that the work wasn't mine.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why you chose the logic like that.  However, intuitively, this is what I am going to do:

1 find mid point location (you can simply contruct the last line and find the mid-point)

2 a function to construct a line, by simply do (psuedo-code):

```
String getLine(int num) {
  String result = "";
  for (int i = num; i > 0; i--) {
    result = result + i + " "; 
  }
  for (int i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
    result = result + i + (i == num? "" : " ");
  }
  return result;
}
```

3 do a loop to print each line:

```
int midPoint = .....; //
for (i=0; i < num; i++) {
    String line = getLine(i+1);
    print (midPoint - mid point of line) spaces;
    print line
}
```

---

Update:

Have briefly tested, looks good to me:

```
public static String getLine(int num) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = num; i > 0; --i) {
        result = result + i + " ";
    }
    for (int i = 2; i <= num; ++i) {
        result = result + i + (i == num ? "" : " ");
    }
    return result;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 15;
    int midPoint = getLine(num).length()/2 + 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        String line = getLine(i+1);
        int noPrefix = midPoint - (line.length()+1)/2 ;
        for (int j = 0; j < noPrefix; ++j) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

result :

```
                                  1 
                                2 1 2
                              3 2 1 2 3
                            4 3 2 1 2 3 4
                          5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5
                        6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6
                      7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
                    8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
                  9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
               10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
            11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
         12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
      13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
   14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Comment: Appreciate your help. I chose that logic because I'm about a week into learning Java. I fully understand I'm not very good at it, but I'm trying.

Comment: kind of get your logic now (I wasn't very clear before :P )  What you are lacking is: instead of printing the prefixed spaces for each by simply by (row - column), use my hints to find out the correct indentation.  It is easier to first construct each line without prefix spaces, and find out correct number of spaces to print then print the result line.  You can see my code is actually similar to yours (esp the `getLine` function).  Shouldn't be hard for you to go one further step to do something similar

Comment: Update: added a piece of working code base on the idea.  Should work even for number > 100

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but here's a solution using [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and printing it out only at the end.

The idea is to calculate the amount of padding required *based on the String equivalent* of the current value.
**Note:** The solution is **not efficient (with all the conversion to String)**, but it can be used for any input value.

**Working Example:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IntegerPyramid {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter # of lines: ");
        int numLines = sc.nextInt();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        System.out.println();

        for(int row = 1; row <= numLines; row++) {

            for(int num = -numLines; num <= numLines; num++) {
                if(num == -1 || num == 0)
                    continue;

                int value = Math.abs(num);
                int padding = String.valueOf(value).length() + 1;

                if(value <= row) {
                    // Print numbers
                    sb.append(String.format(("%" + padding + "d"), value));
                }
                else {
                    // Print spaces
                    sb.append(String.format(("%" + padding + "s"), ""));
                }
            }
            sb.append("\n");
        }

        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter # of lines: 6

           1          
         2 1 2        
       3 2 1 2 3      
     4 3 2 1 2 3 4    
   5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5  
 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6

Enter # of lines: 15

                                   1                                  
                                 2 1 2                                
                               3 2 1 2 3                              
                             4 3 2 1 2 3 4                            
                           5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5                          
                         6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6                        
                       7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7                      
                     8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8                    
                   9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9                  
                10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10               
             11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11            
          12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12         
       13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13      
    14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14   
 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Answer (score -2):

You've got the conditional backwards, believe it should be

```
System.out.print((num >= 10) ? " " + num : num)
```

Easier to understand

```
System.out.print((num < 10) ? num : num : " " + num)
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, Scott. Your second suggestion produces an error, and the first gets the columns out of order.

Comment: yes, I had an extra "num :" in the second one, but since this is an obvious homework assignment, figured identifying the conditional was backwards should have been enough for you to move forward.  If not, then you're in tough straits, programming is all about problem solving.

Comment: Scott, my comment came off as being rude and that wasn't my intention. I'm still learning the syntax, and conditionals within print lines are something we haven't covered. When I placed the first piece of code into the last for statements it correctly spaces 10-15, but there is no spacing between 1-9. I'm clearly not doing something right, but I'm not sure what it is.